# Slice cannot be indexed by `usize`?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to construct a trait (`ByteArray`) which abstracts away an owned sequence versus a borrowed sequence.  For example, it would allow me to do this:

```rust
struct Container<T:ByteArray> {
   data: T
}
```

Then I could instantiate `Container<Vec<u8>>` (where it owns the data) and also `Container<&[u8]>` (where it doesn't).  My approach is this:

```rust
use std::ops;

pub trait ByteArray : ops::Index<usize,Output=u8> {
    fn len(&self) -> usize;
}

impl ByteArray for Vec<u8> {
    fn len(&self) -> usize { self.len() }
}

impl<'a> ByteArray for &'a [u8] {
    fn len(&self) -> usize { self.len() }
}
```

Logically, this seems reasonable to me.  But, it fails with this error:

```
 `&'a [u8]` cannot be indexed by `usize`
```

So, I'm confused about this.  I'm aware that I could implement `ByteArray` for `[u8]`, but that doesn't meet my use case above.  It also seems I can resolve the problem by introducing an intermediary trait, like so:

```rust
pub struct ArraySlice<'a,T>(&'a [T]);

impl<'a,T> ops::Index<usize> for ArraySlice<'a,T> {
    type Output = T;

    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        &self[index]
    }
}

impl<'a> ByteArray for ArraySlice<'a,u8> {
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.len()
    }
}
```

But, this feels a little hacky to me and I'm assuming there is a better solution.  Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but "abstracts away an owned [anything] versus a borrowed" actually already exists in the standard library. The type you're looking for is called [`Cow<[u8]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html).

Comment: Thanks Silvio --- I think that is the best answer!!

Comment: Worth pointing out that `Cow` can vary between owned and borrowed at runtime, and so incurs a slight bit of overhead. For compile-time selection, [`AsRef<[u8]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) could work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Deref`:

```rust
pub trait ByteArray 
where
    Self: ops::Deref,
    <Self as ops::Deref>::Target: ops::Index<usize, Output = u8>,
{
    fn len(&self) -> usize;
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a80beaaa3622bde2d94f582ed2e0f74f)